# Add accessibility to React-leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, accessibility, wai-aria, react-leaflet

Morning all,
I've created an SPA with React-leaflet and its all working perfectly except when it comes to accessibility.

My map has multiple markers added automatically but when I try to tab into the map all I get is the zoom in/out buttons and the maps name, the markers are completely ignored so I cant add ARIA to them.

Does anyone know if its possible to add tabbing for each marker?
Ideally I'd like to have it so when users tab onto a marker it reads the specific data, however if this isnt possible I'm open to suggestions.

Heres how I'm generating/populating the map if it helps:

Markers:--

```
const showDataOnMap = (countryList, y) => (
        countryList.map(country => (
            <Circle
                key = {country.country}
                center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
                fillOpacity={0.4}
                pathOptions={{color:casesTypeColors[y].hex,
                fillColor:casesTypeColors[y].hex}}
                radius={
                    Math.sqrt(country[y] * 12000)
                }
                eventHandlers={{
                    click: () => {
                      console.log(mapRef.current)
                    },
                  }}
                tabIndex="0"
                aria-label="circle"
            >
                <Popup tabIndex="0" aria-live="polite" ref={mapRef}>
                    <div>
                        <img className="mapFlag" src={country.countryInfo.flag} alt={country.country} role="image"/>
                        {country.country}
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        {`${y}: ${numeral(country[y]).format("0,0")}`}
                    </p>
                </Popup>

            </Circle>
        )
    )
    )
```

Map:--

```
return (
    <div className="map" aria-label={`World-map-${active}`} tabIndex="0" role="application">
        <MapContainer center={coords} zoom={2}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            aria-label="Copyright-information"
            aria-hidden="true"
            />
            {showDataOnMap(table,checkActive())}
        </MapContainer>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted the issue.
Adding ARIA to React leaflet components was the problem, it just kept ignoring them so I added a wrapper within Popup in my case and the issues resolved.

```
                 <Popup>
                    <div className="popWrapper" tabIndex="0" ref={mapRef}>
                    <div>
                        <img className="mapFlag" src={country.countryInfo.flag} alt={country.country} role="image" aria-hidden="true"/>
                        {country.country}
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        {`${y}: ${numeral(country[y]).format("0,0")}`}
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </Popup>
```

So now when the Circles clicked I force focus on the popWrapper div and the contents is read.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `tabindex` on the `<Circle>` element so I'm assuming you already know how [tabindex](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-tabindex-attribute) works.  Adding tabindex to your markers will allow them to be <kbd>TABBED</kbd> to.

However, elements that you can <kbd>TAB</kbd> to should be interactive elements.  Do your markers do anything when clicked on or hovered over?  The marker will need a "role" ([WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value)) if it's a keyboard focusable element.  If all you want the marker to do is announce the data value, then perhaps [`role="tooltip"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tooltip) would suffice.  Possibly [`role="note"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#note) would work too, but that's a bit of a stretch because the data value might not be considered "ancillary".

I also noticed you're using `aria-hidden="true"` on the `<TileLayer>`.  Are your markers added as child nodes to `<TileLayer>`?  `aria-hidden` set on a parent container will propagate down to the children and they'll be hidden from assistive technology too.  Setting `aria-hidden="false"` on child elements probably **won't** fix the problem because values of "false" aren't fully supported.  See the second "NOTE" in the [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden) spec:

> **Note** 
> At the time of this writing, `aria-hidden="false"` is known to work inconsistently in browsers. As future implementations improve, use caution and test thoroughly before relying on this approach.

Comment: First things first, brilliant name, @slugolicious. Thanks for the comment, I've removed aria-hidden="true" and added that role of tooltip but unfortunately the issue remains, currently when you click the circles a popup appears with specific info so technically they're interactive. Could the issue be that the circles are added dynamically?

Comment: Ha, I didn't even notice your ID. I guess there are lots of slugs out there. Adding elements dynamically is not a problem for accessibility nor should it be a problem for keyboard navigation (tabindex). Are you saying you're adding elements with `tabindex=0` but tabbing to them doesn't work? Do you have a working example?

Comment: Thanks for the continued support bud, but I've fixed the issue now. Not sure why but for whatever reason I was unable to tab to React-leaflet components. Just added a content wrapper div inside the Popup component has fixed the issue.